# PHP - setCookies issue with 302 code response

Tags: php

I get the following issue with this code : The `localhost` page caused too many redirections. 
Status code is `302 Found`. 
After deleting last else, I come succesfull to my site with `200 OK` respone but then `$user` is not defined.

```
if (empty($_GET['unique_user'])) {
  if (!empty($_COOKIE['unique_user_D_']) && mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `hash`='".myFunction($_COOKIE['unique_user_D_'])."' LIMIT 1"))!=0) {
    header('Location: ./?unique='.$_COOKIE['unique_user_D_']);
    exit();  
  }
  newUser($add);
}
else { 
  if (mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `hash`='".myFunction($_GET['unique_user'])."' LIMIT 1"))!=0) {
    $user=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($polaczenie, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `hash`='".myFunction($_GET['unique_user'])."' LIMIT 1"));
    $unique=myFunction($_GET['unique_user']);
    setcookie('unique_user_D_',myFunction($_GET['unique']),(time()+60*60*24*365*5),'/');  
  }
  else {
    setcookie('unique_user_D_',false,1),'/');
    header('Location: ./');    
    exit();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you are calling:

```
header('Location: ./');    
exit();
```

Which redirects the current page to the `Location: ./` (HTTP Code 302) and I guess the `Location` is the same path as this code = leading to `Too Many Redirects` since you are always redirecting to the same page.

Removing the code (`header` and `exit`) should solve your problem.